# Failure to upload HellowWorld.apk to AVD, using IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to create and run a simple HelloWorld Android application using IntelliJ, but it fails to start - the AVD window displays but the application fails to load. Here's the output I receive:

[image]

This is my first attempt at writing an Android application. I followed this very helpful [tutorial](http://www.java-javafx.com/2013/02/first-android-application-on.html) to get this far, but I'm struggling to find more information regarding this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the size of the **internal storage** I specified for my AVD. I had 16GB - based on the HTC One S. After resetting this to the default 200MB, it worked.

Unfortunately, I don't know why exactly this causes the error I received... if anyone can provide insight into it, I'd love to know. Even simply why 16GB seems to be to much.